# How to append two pointers?

Tags: c, ansi-c

Can someone help me with this code. I need to append these two pointers together but its not working for me. The code does not add the pointers together. I think *mystrcat function is wrong.

```
// stringAdds.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

char *mystrcat(char *s, char *p);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char myChar = 0;
    int i = 0;

    char *s = (char*) malloc (1);
    char *p = (char*) malloc (1);

    printf("Input s: ");
    while ((myChar=getchar()) != '\n')
    s[i++]=myChar;
    s[i]='\0';
    //scanf("%s", &s);
    printf_s("%s", s);

    printf("\nInput p: ");
    i = 0;
    while ((myChar=getchar()) != '\n')
    p[i++]=myChar;
    p[i]='\0';
    printf_s("%s\n", p);

    printf_s("return string: %s", mystrcat(s,p));   
}

char *mystrcat(char *s, char *p)
{
    int sizeOfs = 0;
    int sizeOfp = 0;
    int sizeZero = 0;

    while(*s!='\0')
    {
        sizeOfs++;
    }
    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        sizeOfp++;
    }
    for( int i=0; i<sizeOfp; i++) 
        {
            s[sizeOfs++]=p[sizeZero++];
        }
    s[sizeOfs]='\0';

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Helpful SO hint, you can make corrections to your closed question (fixing the reason why it was closed) and click the "flag" and ask a mod to reopen it. That way you don't need to duplicate things

Answer (score 3):

Since this is probably a homework, here are some hints:

Inside `mystrcat`

- `while(*s!='\0')` is an infinite loop, because `s` does not change inside loop's body
- You do not need to know the size of `p`
- Store `s` so that you could return its value
- Move `s` to the end of the string using a loop
- Copy `p`'s characters into what's pointed to by the new `s` pointer until you hit `'\0'`
- You are done

Outside `mystrcat`

- Your `mystrcat` function assumes that `s` has enough space to store all characters of `s`, all characters of `p`, and a null terminator. Your code `malloc`s the space enough to hold just the null terminator. You need to change the logic to provide more space.
- Everything that you `malloc` must be `free`d.

Comment: could you please go more into detail

Comment: what could i do inside the loops body

Comment: does it matter if I store 's' as a int type

Comment: @jeniffer_214 The first loop should be `while(*s++);` (empty body), the second loop should be `while (*s++=*p++);` (also an empty body).

Comment: @jeniffer_214 -  `•You do not need to know the size of p`. Just to make sure you don't get confused, the size of `p` thing came from pseudo-code I gave you on the original question for this problem. dasblinkenlight is saying you don't need that if your function `assumes that s has enough space to store all characters of s, all characters of p, and a null terminator.`. You'll need to figure out which way you want to implement `mystrcat`, but either `s` needs the memory going in as per his suggestion or you need to find the string sizes as per my original suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your malloc is only 1 byte, but your placing potentially many chars into *s and *p.  You need to at least have storage for every character before you place them into your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean just this? I think there's some missing de-referencing in your example.

```
char *strcat (char *dest, const char *src)
{
char *dp;
char *sp = (char *)src;

if ((dest != NULL) && (src != NULL))
{
    dp = &dest[strlen(dest)];

    while (*sp != '\0')
    {
        *dp++ = *sp++;
    }
    *dp = '\0';
}
return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```
char *ss=s;
while(*ss!='\0')
{
    sizeOfs++; ss++;
}
char *pp=p;
while(*pp!='\0')
{
    sizeOfp++; pp++;
}
```

You basicaly had an infinite loop. I would also malloc bigger size in order to not cause any memory overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Jeniffer, I have to admit, this looks very similar [to the code I mentioned to you before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165470/appending-strings-with-pointers-using-ansi-c)

But you're missing a few of the key elements.

First, when I was doing the initial `malloc()`:

```
char * str1 = malloc(6); // give string 1 some memory
```

I did it such that there was enough for what I was going to put in the string ("hello" in that example). You're trying to get the strings dynamically until you see a `'\n'`. So if you want to use this approach you'll have to allocate something "big enough".

```
char *s = (char*) malloc (1);
```

This can't be "big enough" because the string has to have at least room for a character and a `'\0'` or else it's not a string, just a character. :)

You really can't determine what "big enough" is, so if there's no cap on the string size then just grab some memory and get more if you get close to over flowing it:

```
char *s = (char*) malloc (50); //That's better, room for some char's
```

---

Second point you missed, in the `mystrcat()` function, see the line I put in there:

```
// We need more memory for s, it was only made to hold its own string so :
s = realloc(s, length of s + length of p + 1);  // +1 for NULL terminator
```

You can [read up on realloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) but basically it can give you more memory. When you are concatenating your strings, you probably need to get more memory. That was the point of counting the size of `a` and `p`.

---

Third point, the pseudo-code I gave you was:

```
while(s's character is not '\0')
```

What you're doing won't work. You need to check the characters with in the string against `'\0'` like:

```
while(s[counter] != '\0')
```

and incrementing counter as you go.